# How can I remap a generic USB foot switch?

Tags: windows, keyboard, media, transcription

I bought a USB foot switch that "works", but only as the button "enter". I tried to remap it the whole morning, but Windows is determined to only recognize it as enter, without distinction to the normal keyboard enter.

Notice that I tried most softwares that I found online, Footswitch, etc. Nothing recognizes it, or distinguishes from the enter button.

I want to turn the switch into a play/pause button.

Comment: Did the device come with any software that you installed?

Comment: Is it a USB HID device?  If so, maybe see [How can I remap the keys for a specific keyboard?](https://superuser.com/q/514024/)

Comment: It came with a CD, but I don't have an optical drive. I'll check that link, thanks.

Comment: Try Clavier+ (or perhaps X-Mouse Button Control or AutoHotkey), which can differentiate similar keys on a keyboard, e.g., left-Alt vs. Right-Alt, on the chance it can differentiate the pedal from Enter.

Comment: It is an HID device. HIDmacros seems to differentiate the keyboards, but I can't find the control for play/pause.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely https://pcsensor.com/software or else have a look at the disk to see the name of the software.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1149829)